# ANOVA test on groups with replicates

Tags: r, anova, stat

I have 3 independent groups and want to know which of these group means are different.

My dataset looks as below

```
    T1  T2  T3  T4  H1  H2  H3  S1  S2  S3
A   22  19  16  13  10  19  16  13  10  7
B   55  52  49  46  43  52  49  46  43  40
C   26  23  20  17  14  23  20  17  14  11
D   84  81  78  75  72  81  78  75  72  69
E   95  92  89  86  83  92  89  86  83  80
F   45  42  39  36  33  42  39  36  33  30
G   35  32  29  26  23  32  29  26  23  20
H   84  81  78  75  72  81  78  75  72  69
I   39  36  33  30  27  36  33  30  27  24
```

I am aware of how to do ANOVA for single vector group, but here I have 3 (T, H and S) groups with replicates, can someone please help how to do the one way ANOVA test for the above data.

Comment: What have you tried so far? What SO posts have you read that didn't help?